# Flutter & GraphQL

Tags: express, graphql

### Not sure why am I getting this error.
Please help.
[image]

```
const express = require('express');
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');

const app = express();

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    graphiql: true
}));

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Listening to port 4000');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-graphql)

```
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
```